# Paginating Redis data sets in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

When your data is modeled by ActiveRecord, you can use a myriad of tools to paginate your data so you do not necessarily need to load 1,000,000 objects into memory at any given time on your app server. When you have such large data sets as redis sets, sorted sets, lists... are there any tools that will help paginate that data as well? I understand for something like sets, this might not work as there is no deterministic way to retrieve the data incrementally. However, if you're dealing with sorted sets or lists, this should not be an issue I'd imagine. What are some tools to deal with paginating redis data sets in Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

I created a Ruby gem called [redis_pagination](https://github.com/czarneckid/redis_pagination) to do exactly that for Redis sorted sets and lists.